# Attempt to implement a scheduler in STM32F4

Tags: c, stm32f4-discovery

I have a question regarding scheduler implementation. I have tried to implement a scheduler according to my understanding.

In this example, i have taken advantage of the Systick handler provided by STM32, so my handler looks somewhat like this:

```
void SysTick_Handler(void)
{
  HAL_IncTick();
  HAL_SYSTICK_IRQHandler();    

  if(ticks_for_scheduler++==100)
      ticks_for_scheduler=0;    
}
```

I have a scheduler.h file which looks like this:

```
void (*task1)() = read_temp;
void (*task2)() = Display_temp_lcd;
```

and my scheduler.c looks like this:

```
extern uint16_t ticks_for_scheduler;
void sched_system()
{

  if(ticks_for_scheduler==20)
      (*task1)();

  if(ticks_for_scheduler==40)
  {
      (*task2)();
  }   
}
```

The function `sched_system` is called in `main(){while(1){sched_system();}`My goal is to execute `task1` every 20ms, and `task2` every 40ms, but somehow I'm not able to get it right. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong? I don't see the results on my LCD as expected.

Comment: `ticks_for_scheduler`needs to be declared `volatile`.

Answer (score 3):

Your `ticks_for_scheduler` variable simply counts from 0-99 over and over again, one count per millisecond. This means that it contains any particular value once every 100 ms.

In your main function, that's all you're checking for — whether the variable contains a particular value. So each task will only execute once every 100 ms.

> My goal is to execute task1 every 20ms, and task2 every 40ms

In the most general case, where any given task needs to execute every N ms, you need to maintain a separate counter for each task. In the more constrained case in which every period N has a common multiple of 100 ms, you can use a modulo operator:

```
if (ticks_for_scheduler%20 == 0) (*task1)();
if (ticks_for_scheduler%25 == 0) (*task2)();
```

Note that 40 ms does not have 100 ms as a multiple, but you could make the `ticks_for_scheduler` run from 0-199 if you want to use 40 ms as an interval.

There's a more subtle problem here, too. You're assuming that `sched_system()` runs at least every 1 ms, so that it can "see" every possible value of `ticks_for_scheduler`. But if any given task runs for longer than 1 ms, this cannot be guaranteed. You need to take precautions that the operation of your scheduler cannot be perturbed by the tasks themselves, which is a topic far too broad to address here.

Comment: The systick is configured to generate an interrupt every 1ms, i checked it.I would need an oscilloscope to check if it is exactly 1ms. :)O my, you're right i can't make sure that one task takes longer than 1 ms. I guess i need to redesign the whole thing. Thanks!